# .NET 6 EF deleting DB record on an update?

Tags: entity-framework

The entity/model has a child object, during ADD (POST) operations where I just want the parent object to be updated in the database, I simply set the child object to null.  Parent object adds to database just fine and child object doesn't touch the database.

However, when I do an UPDATE (PUT) and set the same child object to null, the parent object is actually deleted from the database and child object not touched in the database?

Model code:

```
namespace PROJ.API.Models
{
    public partial class Todo
    {
        public Todo()
        {
        }
        public long TdoId { get; set; }
        public string TdoDescription { get; set; } = null!;
        public long PtyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Priority? Priority { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class Priority
    {
        public Priority()
        {
        }
        public long PtyId { get; set; }
        public byte PtyLevel { get; set; }
        public string PtyDescription { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Entities code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PROJ.API.Entities
{
    public class Todo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long TdoId { get; set; }
        public string TdoDescription { get; set; } = null!;
        public long PtyId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PtyId")]
        public virtual Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    }

    public class Priority
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long PtyId { get; set; }
        public byte PtyLevel { get; set; }
        public string PtyDescription { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Repository code:

```
        public async Task<Todo?> GetTodoAsync(long tdoId)
        {

            var todo = await _context.Todo.Where(c => c.TdoId == tdoId)
                                          .Include(x => x.Priority)
                                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return todo;
        }
```

Controller code:

```
        [HttpPut()] // UPDATE
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateTodoAsync(Todo todo)
        {

            var eTodo = await _myRepository.GetTodoAsync(todo.TdoId);

            if (todo.Priority == null || todo.Priority.PtyId == 0)
            {
                var priority = await _myRepository.GetPriorityAsync(todo.PtyId);
                if (priority != null)
                {
                    _mapper.Map(priority, todo.Priority);
                }
            }

            _mapper.Map(todo, eTodo);

            await _myRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();

        }
```

My understanding is that setting the child object to null tells EF to NOT perform any operation on it in the database.  TODO.PtyId is setup with a FK to PRIORITY.PtyId in the SQL database but I have NOT defined this in context (OnModelCreating) as I don't "think" I need the Fluent API approach here.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong and/or why an UPDATE is actually deleting a record when I set a child object to NULL?  As I noted before an ADD using the same null approach works just fine.

Comment: Can't test right now, but I'm pretty sure making the member `virtual` enables the EF proxy, which will try to be smart for you. Try removing virtual and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

In your example and naming convention you should be explicitly nominating your FK either by attribute or fluent declaration. EF's convention is to base FK names on the "type" of the relationship, not the property name. So for instance if you have:

```
public virtual Priority? Pty { get; set; }
```

EF will be looking for a FK named Priority_ID or PriorityID, not PtyID. This behaviour may have changed in EF Core, I honestly haven't delved back into whether EF conventions can be trusted to work this out.

Lastly, this is overall a typical example of issues that can come up whenever you mix concerns with entities and use detached entities as view models. It's also outlining an issue with your repository implementation. In your case you are detaching an entity, then when passing it back to the server to update, loading the entity from data state, and using Automapper to copy the values across.

The first problem is that your repository is automatically and unconditionally eager-loading the related entity when in at least this example you don't need or want that related entity. When EF eager loads a relationship and then you set that related entity to #null, the proxy records this action and EF will interpret that as "Remove this relationship". If the related entity is not loaded/associated and left as #null when saving that top-level entity, nothing is removed. Either way you will want to avoid doing something like setting a related entity to #null if you don't want to save changes to them. The solution is either not to load related entities in the first place, ignore mapping across related entities, or marking those entities as Unchanged to avoid persisting changes to them.

Not loading Related entities:
This could either be solved by adding arguments to indicate what should be eager loaded, or considering adopting `IQueryable` for the repository method:

Argument:

```
public async Task<Todo?> GetTodoAsync(long tdoId, bool includeRelated = true)
{
    var query = _context.Todo.Where(c => c.TdoId == tdoId);
    if (includeRelated)
    {
       query = query.Include(c => c.Pty);
    }
    
    return query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

In simple cases this isn't too bad, but in more complex entities it can be a pain, especially if you want to selectively include relatives. This way when you load eToDo from data state, you can tell it to not eager load the Priority. This isn't foolproof as it is still possible that a Priority could be associated if that DbContext instance had previously loaded the Priority associated with that Todo. Tracked entities will be associated even if you don't explicitly eager load them. To be safe this should be combined with the Automapper changes further below.(Excluding mapping changes) This is still a worthwhile change as you can avoid resource/performance costs of unconditionally eager loading every read.

IQueryable:

```
public IQueryable<Todo> GetTodoById(long tdoId)
{
    var query = _context.Todo.Where(c => c.TdoId == tdoId);

    return query;
}
```

`IQueryable` gives your consumer a lot more flexibility into what it wants to do with regards to data that will be coming back, but it does require a shift in thinking around the unit of work pattern to move the scope of the DbContext out into a Unit of Work so that consumers are responsible for that scope rather than at the individual repository level. The advantages of this approach are that the unit of work (DbContext scope) can be shared across repositories if needed, and with this pattern your consumer has control over things like:

- Projection using `Select` or `Count`, `Any`, etc.
- `async` vs. synchronous operations.
- Assessing whether or not to eager load related entities.

So as an example with this pattern, the controller or service code would function more like:

```
[HttpPut()] // UPDATE
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateTodoAsync(Todo todo)
{
    using (var contextScope = _contextScopeFactory.Create())
    {
        var eTodo = await _myRepository.GetTodoById(todo.TdoId)
            .SingleAsync();

        _mapper.Map(todo, eTodo);

        await contextScope.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();

    }
}
```

contextScope / _contextScopeFactory are a UoW pattern called DbContextScope by Medhi El Gueddari for EF6 which has a number of forks covering EF Core. I like this pattern as it gives the Repository a dependency to a locator to resolve the DbContext from the Scope rather than passing around DbContext instances, giving that scope full control over whether or not `SaveChanges()` gets committed or not. Leveraging `IQueryable` enables projection so it can help avoid this issue all-together when used to read data to send to a view to Project to a ViewModel using Automapper's `ProjectTo` rather than sending Entities to a View which come back to the controller as a deserialized and typically incomplete shell of what they once were.

Excluding mapping changes:

This involves adjusting the mapping you use to exclude copying across changes to the related entity when mapping one Todo across to another.  If the mapping ignores Todo.Pty then you can map across just the Todo fields from the one instance to the DB instance and save the DbInstance without change tracking tripping anything changing in Pty or the relationship.

Marking as Unchanged:

Given your repository is managing the scope of the DbContext what you will likely need to do is add a method to isolate changes to just that top-level entity. Since the Repository is scoping the DbContext, this means some form of clunky method since we need to pass the entity to tweak tracking.

```
// eTodo.Pty = null; don't do
_myRepository.IgnoreRelatedChanges(eTodo);
await _myRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then...

```
public void IgnoreRelatedChanges(Todo todo)
{
    _context.Entry(todo.Pty).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that it is clumsy and prone to bugs/exceptions.

In any case that should provide you with some options to consider to solve your issue, and possibly consider for updating your repository pattern.

Comment: Appreciate the response, unfortunately the "Marking as Unchanged" approach didn't work for me with error:  System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Priority.PtyId' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to mark it as unchanged?  That exception seems a bit odd that it was trying to modify something by marking it unchanged. It may be that since this is after the mapper.Map call, you may need to set up the mapper to ensure that eTodo.Pty does not get overwritten by todo.Pty. (I.e. the reference is replaced or any values updated)

Comment: I'd love to share the code, but Stack Overflow seems to only allow me to enter small comments with less than 600 characters.   I used your exact code above in the "Marking as Unchanged" ... after _mapper.Map(todo, eTodo) just before await _myRepository.SaveChangesAsync.  I came up with a work around that I don't like ... check todo.Pty for null or todo.Pty.PtyId = 0 and load a Priority (based on todo.PtyId) entity and map priority to todo.Pty then map todo to eTodo and SaveChangesASync.  EDIT: seems Stack Overflow wants me to edit my original question ... that would just confuse reader?

Comment: Updated my original post to include ForeignKey attribute on entity to remove EF ambiguity.  Added code to work around issue by checking for null or 0 on PrimaryKey property and loading if needed ... this does work.  I could create new entities for updates only but trying not to go that route ... setting EntityState.Unchanged still doesn't seem to work even with FK defined ... ensuring the navigation properties are populated seems to be the only working approach so far (without going the route of creating new entities).  I'm probably missing something, I just don't know what?

Comment: Hmm, that code you added would have some issues as it's checking 2 different scenarios, so I would remove it for now if we ultimately just want to update a Todo without affecting the priority. Let's just go back to the original problem. When you set eTodo.Priority to null, is the issue that the Priority gets deleted, or is it the Todo that is getting deleted? I'd expect the priority is getting deleted, but if the Todo is getting deleted then this may likely be some kind of mapping issue for the relationship. If Todo is getting deleted please add any ModelBuilder config for the HasMany etc.

Comment: Setting Priority to null and the Todo gets deleted, Priority is not modified - this ONLY happens when attempting an Update, when setting Priority to null on an Add, no issue.  I'll try the Fluent approach with HasMany and see what happens and report back.  Alternatively I could create an Update only entity that doesn't include Priority ... this is the pattern Kevin Dockx uses in his .NET 6 Core training course, who I reached out to and he indicated that's a common approach (separate entities for Update).

Comment: Ok, that is extremely weird behaviour. If you are using fluent configuration it would be the starting point to see what is going on. For instance ensuring the Many-to-1 relationship declared for Todo would be `.HasOne(x => x.Priority).WithMany();` not anything like a 1-to-1.  You could also look to attach a profiler to the database to record what SQL statements are being issued through EF. Also, is this a code-first schema or DB first? Are there any triggers, cascade deletes or other oddities in the schema (from previous design?)

Comment: It looks like AutoMapper is the source of my issues.  When I don't use AutoMapper and manually map the values, I don't have any issues.  I'm using AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection version 11.0.0 by Jimmy Bogard (published Jan 5th 2022) ... I notice there are several extensions from Jimmy (AutoMapper.Data, AutoMapper.EF6, AutoMapper 11.0.1) and some AutoMappers by Tyler Carlson.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Automapper can cause issues, though normally with related entities, not the top level one. Using Mapper.Map to copy values from one ToDo to another shouldn't result in marking the destination as to be deleted. You should just need a version of "Automapper" by jbogard. Automapper.EF6 is for Framework 4.8.x and EF6, not EF Core 6. When mapping to an entity you should configure the mapping to only permit changes in properties you allow to change. Naming the entity and DTO/ViewModel the same can make it a bit tougher to spot potential issues.

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm discovering that Automapper is significantly slower than if I just did my own code to assign what I want assigned/mapped.  I could configure Automapper to work on specific properties but that is slower and to be frank, more confusing for other programmers ... they'll wonder why I'm doing this extra work that is ultimately slower execution and not really saving code since I would need to build profiles per class anyway.  I assume automapper is using a lot of reflection?